# how do i maintain snapshot of data in oracle and couchbase

Tags: oracle, spring-batch, couchbase

I have a spring batch which reads a file daily and insert the data into oracle and couchbase. There are other application which read data from these datasources and for that i just need the latest record data in the tables.

Lets take an example
Day 1: i recieved the file with the below records

```
123,student1,gradeA ( id,name,grade)
124, student2, gradeA ( id, name, grade)
```

Day 2: I received the file with below records

```
123,student1,gradeB ( id,name,grade)
```

So what i need to do is

```
 1. on Day1 I should insert all the records of the file as initially table is empty
 2. On Day2 I need to invalidate the record for "124" as that is not in file
 3. On Day2 Update the record for "123" with new grade
```

So on day 2 if any read request comes for "124" i should throw exception (data not found).

Couple of approaches i thought about

```
Approach 1:
```

> I can have a revision number column in the table and every day a file
>   is read i get the unique revision number for that day and while
>   inserting records into DB for that day i use the revision number. But
>   for this, i need to store the revision number somewhere else and every
>   time i need to read data i have to do an extra lookup to get the
>   current version number.

```
Approach2:
```

> Every time a record is updated maintain last_modified_date column and
>   after batch run which ever is not modified remove those records(this
>   might be costly).

The above approaches might work for oracle, but for couchbase i am thinking of having TTL for every record to solve this.

Can someone suggest any other better approaches on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd be cautious of the TTL in Couchbase. In the event that your batch schedule is delayed, you'd lose all your data.

Approach 2 seems the cleanest to me, and you can leverage a merge/upsert in both Oracle and Couchbase to insert/update accordingly. In Oracle, you'd want either a physical or temporary staging table to improve your `MERGE` performance. And for Couchbase, you'd use a bulk `UPSERT`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flag to maintain record validation.
Every day all records will be marked as 'not valid' and during batch process add record if missing or mark record as 'valid' if it is already present.